# Error al abrir la terminal Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Instale SqlServer en Linux pero  encuentro el siguiente error, al el  monento de abrir la terminal.

bash: /home/fer/.bashrc: línea 171: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `export'
bash: /home/fer/.bashrc: línea 171:`esac export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"'

y este es el código final del .bashrc

```html
153     # Show the currently running command in the terminal title:
154     # http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/xterm-titles-with-bash.html
155     update_tab_command()
156     {
157         # catch blacklisted commands and nested escapes
158         case "$BASH_COMMAND" in
159             *\033]0*|update_*|echo*|printf*|clear*|cd*)
160             __el_LAST_EXECUTED_COMMAND=""
161                 ;;
162             *)
163             put_title "${BASH_COMMAND}"
164             ;;
165         esac
166     }
167     preexec_functions+=(update_tab_command)
168     ;;
169 *)
170         ;;
171 esac export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
172 export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
173 export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
174 export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
175 export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
176 export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
177 export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
178 export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
```

Comment: Parece un fin de `case` huérfano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tal vez sea muy tarde pero si a alguien le ocurre lo mismo.
la solucion es darle un salto de linea despues de "esac"

```
                put_title "${BASH_COMMAND}"
            ;;
        esac
    }
    preexec_functions+=(update_tab_command)
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac 
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
```